# Can Teams messages be searched along with Outlook Email messages?

Tags: microsoft-outlook, microsoft-teams, sharepoint-online

I'm tired of having to flip back and forth between Teams and Outlook to look for communications.

Is it possible to search all of them in one place?  Maybe in a web interface somewhere?

Comment: What do you want to search for in outlook? Calendar item or something else?

Comment: AFAIK no, there's MS graph where you could create an app to search multiple sources. But I doubt that's really what you are looking for. Teams search is terribly bad in my opinion.

Comment: How are you doing with this issue? Is there anything you would like to update? Thanks!

Comment: @Christy Kind of looks like nobody knows.

Comment: Well, ,maybe you could provide more information about your issue for our better research, such as the information about my question above.